# JSF2.0 @Viewscoped beans not replicating in clustered environment

Tags: jsf-2

Deployed JSF2.0 in the cluster environment on Apache tomcat server. How to replicate view scoped beans in the clustered environment?

Most of the beans are in viewscoped and state saving method is client.

The problem is : when I opened Home.xhtml first request goes to node 1. View-scoped bean was created. Clicked on action button for processing and loading the same view now request goes to node 2 - where the view doesn't exist.JSF creating new viewscoped bean, this is where I am loosing my previous state in node1.

On the other hand JSF view-state may not work properly in cluster environment. How to use JSF2 in clustered environment?

Are there any other solutions other than session replication and sticky session?

Comment: Session replication or sticky session is the answer. Not doing so has many other side effects than broken view scope. Not sure why you don't want to use the right solutions you apparently already know.

Comment: BaluC, Thanks for your reply. Due to architectural constraints not able to use session replication or sticky session. Is there any work around for this problem?

Comment: If the cluster architecture is not designed for stateful web applications, then you'd better redesign your web application as a stateless one (i.e. stick to request scoped beans and manually carry around the state via request parameters).

Comment: BalusC, Thanks again for your reply. One final question :). Storing view state in the client side. If any field(s) changed in the view JSF should update the changes in the model right, Irrespective of which node it's going?

Answer (score 0):

JSF viewscope, client state saving, can work in cluster environment if the application post entire request in a single request,Do not try to send partial page request.

If you change some of the fields in UI will be replicated in the server by JSF because you are sending the entire state instead of partial state.